# ctrl+enter runs cell and ADDs and newline

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

When running Jupyter lab, cntrl+enter runs the cell (great!) and adds a newline (not great!). When I check keyboard shortcuts it shows Insert Line Break and Run Selected Cell and Do not Advance both being tried to ctrl+enter. When I try to change Line Break to just enter, it keeps on defaulting back to cntl+enter.

Has anyone exercised this? (and even better solved it!)

Tried changing keyboard shortcut. Keeps going back.